# MOSFET and LED Circuit

Tags: mosfet

I am trying to use a MOSFET as a switch for my LEDS. I have 6 LEDS in series connected from 9V to gnd and for the gate of the mosfet i will be connecting from a microcontroller. This will be providing 1.5-5.5V. Just asking will this mosfet work well? [IRFZ44R Data sheet](http://www.vishay.com/docs/91291/91291.pdf)

Answer (score 2):

Your concept is not completely wrong, but there are some things to keep in mind:

1. 9V may not be sufficient to supply 6 LEDs in series, since the total voltage drop will be the sum of the individual forward voltages. Consider connecting two series of 3 LEDs in parralel instead.
2. An LED's significant operating parameter is its current, not the voltage applied. As the voltage across an LED decreases with rising temperature, the LED current will increase due to self heating, which leads to a thermal runaway and possible damage to the LED. Use a series resistor (or a constant current source) to limit the LED current to a reasonable level.
3. In the datasheet you linked in your question, RDS(On) is only specified at VGS = 10V. At VGS = 5.5V, RDS will most likely be low enough for your application. However, at VGS = 1.5V, RDS will not allow any significant current flow through the LEDs, resulting in a faint glow at best. A logic level mosfet like the [IRLI520](http://www.irf.com/product-info/datasheets/data/irli520npbf.pdf) requires a lower VGS value to reach its minimal RDS.

Comment: I will take the number of LEDS in mind (I can reduce it to 3 or 4 or 5 pretty easily, 6 is not the set number). As for your last point I tried to find another mosfet easily accessible to me and I came up with this.
http://www.irf.com/product-info/datasheets/data/irl3303.pdf

If I am correct this has 2 turn on voltages 1 at 4.5V which should be low enough for me. Correct?

Comment: Yes, it will work. RDS will reach the specified value at VGS=4.5V.